# Do subprocess.Popen calls inside a function get garbage collected when the function exits scope?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

I have a Flask application where there are links that open Jupyter notebooks. In the function that handles the url, the Jupyter notebooks are opened by a call to subprocess.Popen. Especially on Windows, after some time, the notebooks seems to be dead, i.e. they have lost connection to the kernel, and I can only get them to work again by clicking on the Flask link again. I have not noticed this behavior on a Mac. This makes me think that maybe the subprocess is getting closed. It isn't stored in a variable or anything, so once the function exits, there is no scope for it to be in. Does anyone know if this happens, and if so what happens to the process that should be running?

Here is an example of what one of these functions looks like. When you click on a link it calls the open_lecture function, constructs a cmd and Popens it. Then the function exits.

```
@app.route("/lecture/<label>")
def open_lecture(label):
    fname = 'lectures/{}.ipynb'.format(label)

    # Now open the notebook.
    cmd = [JUPYTER]
    cmd += [fname]
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

Is there a way to keep this from happening? Or a better way to programmatically open a jupyter notebook?

Comment: maybe include the code you're using to run the process?  without that we're guessing more than necessary!  first guess would be that the jupyter process is terminating due to stdout/err files filling up

Comment: I have added an example of what a typical function looks like.

Comment: it seems to be as I guessed!  why are you using `PIPE` and not doing anything with them?  this is saying that you will handle the in/output of the process, but are actually just ignoring it.  at some point buffers will fill up and the Jupyter program will probably start to misbehave

Comment: That makes sense I guess. If I leave those out will the processes stay persistent or eventually get garbage collected away?

Comment: I've added some details as an answer, let me know if it isn't clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executed processes should continue after any `Popen` object has been garbage collected, but in your case you have asked for the output to be returned to Python but then you aren't processing the output.  this could do different things depending on how things get cleaned up in Python and how the invoked process handles errors.

as an example, if I run:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["yes"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

(`yes` writes lots of stuff to its stdout) it freezes after writing 64KiB of output, which is what my OS/kernel (Linux 5.3) gives to `pipe`s between processes.  you can confirm by waiting a second, calling `proc.terminate()` then `print(len(proc.communicate()[0]))`.

as you're invoking Jupyter, it'll probably just write status and other informational messages to stdout, so will take a while to fill this buffer which is why you're seeing a sporadic timeout.

Python's garbage collector only works on its own heap (i.e. not other processes, each Python process is independent), so invoked processes will just run as they would according to the semantics of your OS